# Hy28B display with STM32

Tags: spi, stm32f10x

I'm trying to get this Hy28b display work with my stm32f103 MCU. Somehow the display doesn't respond. I've found out I cannot communicate with it, my SPI setup is the following:

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef initSPI;
    initSPI.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
    initSPI.GPIO_Pin  = GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_7; // sck mosi
    initSPI.GPIO_Speed =  GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &initSPI);

    initSPI.GPIO_Pin  =  GPIO_Pin_6;
    initSPI.GPIO_Mode =  GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING; ///miso
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &initSPI);

    SPI_InitTypeDef initStruct;
    SPI_StructInit(&initStruct);
    initStruct.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
    initStruct.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge;
    initStruct.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
    initStruct.SPI_NSS  = SPI_NSS_Soft;
    initStruct.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_32;
        SPI_Init(SPI1, &initStruct);

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1, ENABLE);
    SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitTypeDef initGPIO;
    initGPIO.GPIO_Mode  =  GPIO_Mode_Out_PP; 
    initGPIO.GPIO_Pin   =  GPIO_Pin_4;  //CS
    initGPIO.GPIO_Speed =  GPIO_Speed_50MHz;

        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &initGPIO);
```

And I modified the sample send function:

```
unsigned char STM32_SPI_TxRxByte (unsigned char byte_s)
{
    /* wait for current SPI activity complete */
    while (SPI1->SR&SPI_SR_BSY);

    SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1, (unsigned short) byte_s);

    while((SPI1->SR&SPI_SR_RXNE));

    return (SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1););
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you check the RESET pin of the Display besides the settings from venny?

Comment: You're right buddy! That was my silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I see two major issues with this code. First thing is different SPI mode. Setting \$\texttt{SPI_CPHA_2Edge}\$ and \$\texttt{SPI_CPOL_Low}\$ means mode 0,1 whereas the display expects 1,1.

Another thing is that SS# is constantly low which prevents the display controller to detect the start of the transaction.

Comment: I've edited the code:
 initStruct.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_1Edge;
 initStruct.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
But the display still doesn't respond.

Comment: @erbal Try it with mode 11,which is SPI_CPHA_2Edge and SPI_CPOL_High. Also note that you are missing ! in \$\texttt{while(!(SPI1->SR&SPI_SR_RXNE));}\$.

Comment: In my functions I also employ dummy read before writing to SPI data register, to be sure that RXNE is zero.